# How can i give link in block for only listed paths based on user id?

Tags: blocks

I have created block and i want to give the only listed paths

i.e user/user_id   ex: user/123

i have given **user/***  but it displays all pages where users pages are there.

i tried below ways[image]

and enabled PHPFILTER and tried this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try "extended_block_visibility" module, install it and then on block setting page select last option "pages on which this php code will return true" and then you can write php code inside php tag like :

```
<?php
if(arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric(arg(1))){
return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;
?>
```

But remember this code will save inside the DB and will break site if write wrong code. Alternatively you can define theme specific visibility using this module.

Comment: ok will try and let you know.

Comment: That will definitely work if you will face any problem then let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can use path alias, for example If my user's page alias is `/users/myusername`
then you can set `users/*` in *Visibility settings*. So it will be available on `user/*` page, but not on `user/*/*` pages.